# Отправка POST без формы PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста. Почему обработка POST не происходит на стороне контроллера? Код:

```
$query = http_build_query([
                'service_id' => $data->id,
                'target' => $request->address,
                'quantity' => $request->quantity
            ]);
            $options = stream_context_create([
                'http' => [
                    'header' => [
                        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    ],
                    'method' => 'post',
                    'content' => $query
                ]
            ]);
            $generate = file_get_contents('https://epsmm.com/api/v1/orders?token=aLUkpx-YsC4gBsY4dh-k', false, $options);
```

Выводит ошибку
file_get_contents(https://epsmm.com/api/v1/orders?token=aLUkpx-YsC4gBsY4dh-k): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: В `stream_context_create()` протокол `https` вместо `http` попробуйте.

Comment: ещё можете попробовать запрос сделать с помощью `curl`